# How to check presence of ::after in pseudoelement javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to check if a span is clicked for automation purposes, the only change in the element is `::after` inside the span, how can I verify the presence of `::after` ?

[this is the span after clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0IqS.png)

Comment: how is the `::after` *added* by the click?

Comment: have you tried using the CSS with `:after` pseudo element?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. pseudo elements are not in the DOM and so cannot be selected by Javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D in this particular case it's possible because a read-only is need to verify this